# How to save logs in DB on all loggers via spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hi I am trying to save the logs of my app in DB via AOP. any suggestions.

Ex:

```
 logger.info("In Business - {}", value);
```

I want this log in business to save in database as well after printing here.

Looking for some AOP which I may apply on Logger.info

https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-aop-with-spring-boot-starter-aop

Comment: There's a `Appender` too insert log to database http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender

Answer (score 0):

according to my understanding, people usually don't do that because of DB overhead.

What I did previously is to create an entity directly and call that service to save whichever you wanted to log. You can find the following for your reference.

```
public class MyLogger{
    private String message;

    // Getter
    // Setter
}

public class MyLoggerService(){
    @Autowired
    private MyLoggerRepo repo;

    public void save(String message){
        MyLogger log = new MyLogger();
        log.setMessage(message);
        repo.save(log);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The log4j API provides the org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender object, which can put logging information in a specified database. You may have a try of this, no need to code by yourself.